# Centering navbar not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm very new to `HTML` and `CSS`. I'm trying to center the `navbar` at the top of a site. Here is my `HTML` code:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<div class="nav_container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top top-nav-collapse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">         
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav page-scroll" style="text-align:center">
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#packages">Packages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#showcase">Showcase</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And here is (some) relevant `CSS` code:

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
}
.nav_container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav_container nav {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

I must apologise in advance if this question looks like a duplicate of other questions. I have tried out different permutations of how the CSS code should be set according to other answered questions, but to be honest how and which class in the CSS code takes precedence is still not clear to me and my `navbar` is just not centering. I took the code from a bootstrap site, and am simply reverse engineering. It could be that what is already written contains some redundant code (for example, there may be too many divs) and so may need to be cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
<div class="nav_container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top top-nav-collapse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
```

To :

```
 <div class="container">  
    <div class="nav_container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top top-nav-collapse" role="navigation">
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/348kt9zh/)

**Note : For See Result increment Result Page.**

Comment: Thanks, no change :(

Comment: you use bootstarp?

Comment: I forget the site, something like "Built with bootstrap", then I changed a lot of the code.

Comment: I changed this as per your demo. The navbar is now to the left, and changing the style="text-align:center" to left/right has no effect, neither does  "text-align: center" in nav_container. I suspect something is overriding this property and can't figure out what